# People can view the item which was added by them in the SPlist.Not able to view the item which was added by others

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

i want the coding for People can view the item which was added by them in the list.....
[i need to add item in custom splist but that was not able to view by anyone...likewise people who are adding item in the same list which was not able to view by others(i gave permission to view my Splist for the user).]

Comment: I'm sorry can you please reword your question to attempt it to be a little clearer?

Comment: Hi Hugh Wood.... For example if A has added some items to  SPlist, and B has added some items to same SPlist. Now my requirements as follows: A shouldnot able to see what B has added and B should not able to see what A has added ... Please Try to find  answer ASAP.. Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need to set up Item-level Permissions.

Go to list settings -> advanced settings and set Item-level Permissions Read: Read items that were created by the user .

Edit after **Ksesh** comment:

Also set Create and Edit access to : Create items and edit items that were created by the user

Edit programmatically in shortcut:

```
   SPList spList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["MyList"];
   spList.ReadSecurity = 2;
   spList.WriteSecurity = 2;
   spList.Update();
```

Comment: Plus I think permissions to create and change should be also changed to "created by a user"

Comment: hi...thanx for ur answer...but i want to do that by programmatically...

Comment: Ok, you can mark this answer as correct so other can find it.

Comment: hi jedrzej...how to set security for listitem programatically.i have two radio button.(i)view by every one (ii)me only...if i select 'view by every one' radiobutton when i add item to list.that item able to view by everyone.if i select 'me only'.then that item ll view by me ly.plz help me...is there any property to do this..thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without any line of code also i.e. Item-level Permissions in order to do that

1. Move to List Setting of said list.
2. Move to views in the page.
3. Click on "All Items".
4. Move to the filter.
5. check "Show items when the following is true"
6. Put the condition Created By "Is equal To" TYPE([Me])
7. Click on OK.

in short you need to put filter on public view for condition  "Created By "Is equal To" TYPE([Me])"